# Why does my frame shrink once I `setDefaultCloseOperation(false)`?

Tags: java, swing

I have tried to `setDefautCloseOperation(false)` for my frame ***login***. But the frame shrinks down to be practically invisible. Why does this happen? I have encountered this problem many times. Sometimes, when I re-arrange my code it works, but I want to know how to get over this issue? Is it because of the nature of the swing package?

Here is my code:

```
package tester_project;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame login = new JFrame();
        login.setTitle("Login");
        login.setVisible(true);
        login.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        login.setSize(500, 500);
        login.setResizable(false);
    }

}
```

But when I move up the `setDefaultCloseOperation(false);` it works:

```
package tester_project;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame login = new JFrame();
        login.setTitle("Login");
        login.setVisible(true);
        login.setResizable(false);
        login.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        login.setSize(500, 500);
    }

}
```

Does this happen because java supports procedural code? I am new to java so my question might seem trivial, but can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Your frame has no components! Are you trying to set the size to be fixed at 500, 500? "Does this happen because java supports procedural code?" no, that is not why. It is odd that 'setDefaultCloseOperation' is having an effect on the layout, but the bigger issue is you're not setting the layout correctly.

Comment: The setVisible method comes last.  The order of statements should be setTitle, setDefaultCloseOperation,  setSize, setResizable, and lastly setVisible.  The order that the JFrame methods are called is crucial.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: @matt How can I set the layout correctly? I have just started learning java that is why my code seems a bit of a mess.

Comment: What do you want to display? You're example is really good, you've made a minimal example to demonstrate your issue. It is more of an x-y problem though. What do you want to create? Then you build the swing components that take care of that for you.